# Pug/Jade get all variables in a given template

Tags: templates, pug, locals

For a given Jade/Pug template I would like to get a list of all variables which occur within the template.

My motivation is as follows: In my software, different templates are used to generate some HTML snippets. Based on a given context (i.e. values for certain variables are given), I would like to suggest only those templates, where all variables within the template can be assigned.

Example: For template `myTemplate` like this:

```
html
    head
        title= myTitle
    body
        h1 #{value.headline}
        p #{paragraph.text}
```

I would like to get some output like this:

```
var variableNames = extractVariableNamesFromTemplate('myTemplate');
// variableNames = [ 'myTitle', 'value.headline', 'paragraph.text' ]
```

Is there something available ready-to-use? Preferably a solution which would take into account all language-specific features such as includes, extends, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer to your problem but more of a starting point. From debugging the pug code, i have noticed you could probably "hook" a plugin in one of the steps of template "compilation" to code. Look [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/b876a89ca046f55c88bde4ff4c45e8fa66ac149f/lib/index.js#L163).
It seems that in the various steps of compilation, you can access the diffrent nodes present in the template.

You could also look at [this](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-parser), it seems to offer almost what you are looking for.

If you do something like

```
var lex = require('pug-lexer');

var filename = 'template.pug';
var src = `
html
    head
        title= myTitle
    body
        h1 #{value.headline}
        p #{paragraph.text}`;

var tokens = lex(src, {filename});
```

The contents of tokens is an array of the diffrent tokens, the one that are of type "code" or "interpolate-code" seem to be the diffrent variables.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, Mathieu! This looks extremely valuable. It will still require additional logic, e.g. for conditionals and variable assignments, but it is a big step into the right direction. PS: If I should not get a more complete solution within the next two days, the bounty is yours!